# Pair Row data into column data

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a query that returns data in the form

```
[SetID],[COLID],[DataValue],[Order].
1,1,'Value1',1
1,1,'Value2',2
1,1,'Value3',3
1,2,'value4',1
1,2,'Value5',2
1,2,'Value6',3
```

How to make it return the data like

```
[SetID],'Value1','Value4',1
[SetID],'Value2','Value5',2
[SetID],'Value3','Value6',3
```

So that the data tagged with each columnid is back into a column.
The answer appears to be some sort of pivot, but I'm not looking for a straight conversion, or a one-row answer.

Comment: What if the 1, 2, 3 was 1, 2, 3, 4?  What if there are more colid?

Comment: Good questions.  If [Order] goes to 4, there would be 4 rows of data returned.  If there are more colid's, there should be corresponding columns in the result.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to put each data value into a separate column, you need to know the number of *DataValues* and the `ColId` of each. You can't dynamically return variable number of columns (unless you use dynamic SQL to construct the query on the fly), moreover each row needs to have the same number of columns, otherwise the table structure doesn't make sense.

Here's an example that you can quickly test, it uses an in-memory table.

Given the table **MyTable**:

```
declare @MyTable table (SetId int, ColId int, DataValue varchar(20), [Order] int);

insert into @MyTable values (1,1,'Value1',1)
insert into @MyTable values (1,1,'Value2',2)
insert into @MyTable values (1,1,'Value3',3)
insert into @MyTable values (1,2,'Value4',1)
insert into @MyTable values (1,2,'Value5',2)
insert into @MyTable values (1,2,'Value6',3)
```

This query will return the values in separate columns:

```
select mt.SetId, 
        (  select top 1 m1.DataValue from @MyTable m1 
            where m1.SetId = mt.SetId and 
                    m1.[Order] = mt.[Order] and 
                    m1.ColId = 1 -- hard-coded ColId, you need to know its value
        ) 'val1', 
        (   select top 1 m1.DataValue from @MyTable m1 
            where m1.SetId = mt.SetId and 
                    m1.[Order] = mt.[Order] and 
                    m1.ColId = 2 -- same as above
        ) 'val2', mt.[Order]
from @MyTable mt
group by mt.SetId, mt.[Order]
```

> Result:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| SetId | Val1    | Val2   | Order  |
|-------+---------+--------+--------|
|    1  | Value1  | Value4 |    1   |
|-------+---------+--------+--------|
|    1  | Value2  | Value5 |    2   |
|-------+---------+--------+--------|
|    1  | Value3  | Value6 |    3   |
+-----------------------------------+
```

However, I would recommend stuffing all the data values into one column (separated by a delimiter), because this will work with any number of data values. Here's the query:

```
select  mt.SetId, 
        stuff(( select ', '+ m2.DataValue 
                from @MyTable m2 
                where   mt.SetId = m2.SetId and 
                        mt.[Order] = m2.[Order]
          FOR XML PATH('')) , 1, 2, '') 'DataValues',
        mt.[Order]
from @MyTable mt
group by mt.SetId, mt.[Order]
```

> Result

```
+----------------------------------+
| SetId | DataValues       | Order |
|-------+------------------+-------|
|   1   | Value1, Value4   |   1   |
|-------+------------------+-------|
|   1   | Value2, Value5   |   2   |
|-------+------------------+-------|
|   1   | Value3, Value6   |   3   |
+-------+------------------+-------+
```